# webpack with css-loader - Parsing error: ';' expected

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, css-loader

I am starting my first project with React.

To start with, I just have a single component `LikeButton.tsx`, which is injected into the body. I am trying to apply some styles to this button:

```
import './LikeButton.css';
```

*LikeButton.css*:

```
button {
    color: red;
}
```

Here is my *webpack.config.ts*:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|dist)/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [
                    'style-loader', 'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
};
```

When I run `webpack`, I end up with the following error:

```
ERROR in src/components/LikeButton.css:1:7
[unknown]: Parsing error: ';' expected.
  > 1 | button {
      |       ^
    2 |     color: red;
    3 | }
```

The css syntax is correct, so I am guessing the css is being interpreted as javascript/typescript somewhere, but I cannot see where due to the `[unknown]`-part in the error message.

The loader

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin` which of course you may need for typescript / React combination to work properly, specify the files that you want eslint to check

```
eslint: {
             files: './src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}',
          },
```

this tells eslint to check javascript and typescript files only, thus removing the css error.

Answer (score 1):

It was the *Fork TS Checker Webpack Plugin* that caused the issue. By removing it from `module.exports.plugins` in *webpack.config.ts*, the error disappeared:

```
module.exports = {
...
plugins: [
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
            async: false,
            eslint: {
                files: "./src/**/*",
            },
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    ],
}
...
```

Comment: Instead of removing the plugin, you can specify the file types, which will be checked by it. Smth like `files: "./src/**/*.tsx"`.